# How to select multiple properties from object in React

Tags: reactjs, object, filter, properties, array.prototype.map

I am building a search bar in React that searches through a "SlideData".
I am filtering using the "text1" property of the object.
It would be better to parse all of the text in the properties(title,text1,text2,text3).
How would I search all strings within each property?

Beyond that, it would be nice if the word that was searched was highlighted, but i know thats extra work. For clarity, an example would be if I searched for kenny (which is in text3 property) it would show results for "kenny" and only the content from where kenny is originated.right now it would only filter text in text1 property.

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
```

```
const SlideData = [
  {
    slideIndex: 1,
    title: "My name is Bob",
    text1: "Bob likes to eat hamburgers",
    text2: "Kenny likes to eat hot dogs",
    text3: "Terry likes milkshakes"
  },
  {
    slideIndex: 2,
    title: "My name is Jill",
    text1: "Jill likes to eat hamburgers",
    text2: "Joshua likes to eat hot dogs",
    text3: "Steven likes milkshakes"
  }
]
```

```
        <div className="search-results">
          <ul className="search-list">
            {SlideData.filter((item) => {
              if (searchTerm === "") {
                return null;
              } else if (item.text1.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                return item;
              }
            }).map((item) => (
              <div key={item.slideIndex} style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
                <li className="search-item">{item.text1}</li>
                <a
                  className="search-link"
                  onClick={() => {
                    context.setCurrentSlide(item.slideIndex);
                    setSearchTerm("");
                  }}
                 >
                  Go To Slide {item.slideIndex}
                </a>
              </div>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should not perform search operations on the client side. However, in this case, you can simply concatenate all properties to search through them.

```
<div className="search-results">
  <ul className="search-list">
    {SlideData.filter(item => {
      if (searchTerm === '') {
        return null;
      } else {
        let searchText = item.title + item.text1 + item.text2 + item.text3;
        if (searchText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
          return item;
        }
      }
    }).map(item => (
      <div key={item.slideIndex} style={{ padding: '10px' }}>
        <li className="search-item">{item.text1}</li>
        <a
          className="search-link"
          onClick={() => {
            context.setCurrentSlide(item.slideIndex);
            setSearchTerm('');
          }}
        >
          Go To Slide {item.slideIndex}
        </a>
      </div>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>;
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah i normally would query a backend but this is just a slideshow with little information so this is perfect!

Comment: I am glad i could help :)

Comment: do you have n idea about how i could use the <mark> tag in this to highlight the word searched in the results? just curious

Comment: Do you need to highlight the search-item list item?

Comment: in my minds eye i imagine the term that is search to be highlighted in the list results. so if i search hamburger and it showed two results both results would have hamburger highlighted, kind of like cheggs study search

Comment: You would need to find the start and end index of searchTerm inside item text. Then, you can apply custom CSS to that part of string.